# Can't get json from Swagger (swagger-jaxrs)

Tags: jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Actually i am trying to generate swagger.json for my REST services.
i succeeded to do it using jersy, but now we use don't use jersy in our services, we just use Jax-rs, so now i am not able to generate it and got 404 error code.

Here are my pom dependencies

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and this is my app config application

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import com.skios.endpoint.EmployeeEndpoint;
import com.skios.endpoint.ShopsEndpoint;

import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers;

@ApplicationPath("api")
public class AppConfiguration extends Application {

public AppConfiguration() {
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] { "http" });
    beanConfig.setHost("localhost:7070");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("app");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.skios.endpoint");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

    Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet();
    resources.add(ShopsEndpoint.class);
    resources.add(EmployeeEndpoint.class);
    // ...
    resources.add(ApiListingResource.class);
    resources.add(SwaggerSerializers.class);
    return resources;
}
}
```

and these are my end points

```
@Api(value = "/employees", description = "Endpoint for employee listing")
@Path("/employees")
public class EmployeeEndpoint {}

@Path("/shops")
@Api(value="/shops", description="Shops")
public class ShopsEndpoint {}
```

andnow when i am trying to enter the path of swagger.json file

```
http://localhost:7070/MavenSwaggerTest/api/swagger.json

i got 404 error code.
```

so what is the problem? can any one help me? 
thanks

Comment: Do you see any other errors in the logs (on startup)? Can you give a sample URL you use to access your API (which I assume you can successfully do)?

Comment: @Ron: Thank you very much  for replying, But actually i didn't got any errors in console, i am testing that over Tomcat v8, also this is my project >> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1u4YdligQ8YYllFUGVCbm5seHM please check it

Comment: It's not that swagger.json isn't accessible, it's that nothing in your API is accessible - not even your shops resource. JAX-RS is just a spec and a set of interfaces. You can write something generic but you need to hook it to an implementation. swagger-jaxrs will pull in an old version of jersey, but that's not going to be enough. Your first step would be to fix the application so it works.

Comment: @Ron: Thanks for your concern, Actually i removed all dependencies but just kept >> io.swagger swagger-jaxrs version 1.5.6 and added Emplyee and shops classes to resources then run the project over wildfly version 9x instead of Tomcat server and i got it run with no problem, also i got swagger.json file at run time, again thank you very much

Comment: @ Supun Wijerathne Actually your answer didn't help me, as the problem was in project itself not from this configuration, but in general i solved the problem by using only **io.swagger** dependency and ignore other dependencies. BTW Thanks for your answer but i can't mark it as a right answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

You haven't configure your `ApplicationPath` and `BasePath`correctly.

Configure it like this.

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
```

`beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");`

Now `http://localhost:7070/MavenSwaggerTest/api/swagger.json` would work, unless there is any other issue.